# Why can't I make line breaks in my questions/answers?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editor

When
I'm
writing
something, I naturally use a lot of line breaks. Unfortunately, when I press return once to make a linebreak, it
just
adds
a
space.
I
have
to
press
return
again
for
a
break
to
appear,
and
even
then
only
a
paragraph
break
appears.

In fact, for demonstrative purposes, in the above paragraph, I used 'linebreaks' instead of spaces:[image]

I realise I can use `<br />` to add line breaks, but this soon becomes cumbersome.

Might I request that:

- if this is a bug, please fix it?
- if this is a missing feature, please could it be added?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you ***add two spaces*** after a word and enter a line break/return, the markdown engine will insert a line break automagically. This disables the rewrapping that is designed into the editing system.

So
if 
you
enter
lines
like
this, they wrap.

But
if
you
double
space, then they don't wrap.

(click the [history link](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1623/revisions) to see my source)

This is documented in the [advanced editing help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/editing-help) section, which you can get to from any editing frame by clicking the blue circle around the question mark to the right of the edit toolbar.

Comment: That makes sense, though the 'edit' link is greyed out for me so I can't see the source...

Comment: OK, perhaps the revision history will work, but you should be able to test this on your posts. Just use a second space (or more) and see how wrapping changes.

Comment: Does this work or does it time-out (session-specific?) http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/019a3bc0-8d9e-4bc3-9654-a1f4d04875a7/view-source

Comment: It's no longer necessary, but it doesn't time-out, no. I can still read it, 15 days later, so it must be fine :)